# What URL to use with WebSockets?

Tags: javascript, websocket

The examples I see show something like this.

ws://localhost:8000/socket/server/startDaemon.php

I'm testing on localhost on port 8787, so up to there it's understood. I have a server called "chat-server.exe" running on port 8787. How do I set up the file path? In the example above, it says /socket/server/startDaemon.php. What is that file path, where does it start, etc? I'm running on Ubuntu out of Documents/Programs/chat-server. So...?

Note: To be more specific, I mean this when I say 'what URL':

w = new WebSocket( url )

Comment: How are we supposed to know what path your server is listening on? You have not shown any configuration or code.

Comment: I'm not very experienced with network programming, but the server is listening on port 8787, and is running from Documents/Programs/chat-server.exe. What other information should I share?

Comment: How are you running an exe on Ubuntu? WINE or something?

Comment: I guess it isn't literally a .exe. I'm just used to referring to programs that way. It's the filetype produced by compiling with gcc.

Comment: ...although now that I look at it, the properties do say it's an executable.

Comment: Yes, Linux has executable files as well, just not `.exe`s. Anyway, this is neither here nor there. The directory where the executable is stored on disk has no correlation to the URL path where the executable listens for requests. Total shot in the dark: have you tried something as simple as `new WebSocket(localhost:8787)`?

Comment: So, can you explain what that path means? The "socket/server/startDaemon.php"? I was guessing it's the location of the server file on the host, but it seems to be a relative path and I'm not sure where it starts from.

Comment: It's an abstract path in a URL. It looks like a file path, but it is not one.

Comment: I will try your total shot in the dark (which was going to be my guess as well, although I like trying to get more information before stabbing randomly), and get back to you in a little bit.